# How to get participants from this JSON with JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have this json

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "dataVersion": "2",
    "matchId": "NA1_4140996656",
    "participants": [
      "ij9F1fb1dbDRoJVWEAKLSBw7055pF0rS57UCpw_i3xZk369DsZxRxe10y8HdrVZNhEBOcmwFsv2kGQ",
      "eISKLjPm_PqqZYpP4IjyImqblk1ALBT4t4uHLbWz5zuf258L7QU3hCppP6npq9KSxztjMvX_ew6Y2w",
      "bhEBdubtCJxcxhVoP-mU-t4XMfsBSjA7fywEtKVolMBOXwUzS8L2EypzgA0Qvp85JffazahRWdKW3w",
      "HJtgo9vDRFKMEI6PYLccUHjtkwXpgpBt7eGzZeZ7lpsBtdr0xWY7ohXtsHfn15zJ4W_lsNHraiQ_gw",
      "0wTnxcvw5gjZGB5EST7NAU7rXWr7i5Rr515vr8oGY-g4Jz2Jgdh0-ev3bMLf6vplL5IQUsVS9V9n7w",
      "CNtzLyJqZwHrs5Wzwec3FvifA48FMy2I2jGx4hKS1M8FwlIgxB7YimT1akvFRhVe9keJCCzogoL4Og",
      "HDzjdaStxhHcceGGd8qJcc4Vw45FOlOQ1PNXKQ0h9_iqfwHP3oI0spl1bLUOw_7_J49vzaIKylv5Vg",
      "UhdkZRk761qBl4fzQK9MCfUW7qglWQ_-3O5kpg490yPr8lVmlSgpfrO9dRS_r27YpE3QCRgQ5OcVdw",
      "G1mo4nNtBT-2OgzPYxZxZpO3C9Zc12UM-Dr6MaA0nksXBOi5uEUydMJhXAJbTGhRqaZPmJn3yP7OIw",
      "xB_E2Q9B_X-bxCldXmeL9JuABxvDx7_aSEawB2La7a6gINfhENZlNIpMaNde8m78WR2RZdtwlnN5dw"
    ]
  },
```

I was wondering how I can get the list of participants using JSONObject in Java

Comment: It should be simple, did you try anything? By searching, reading JSONObject API docs etc

Comment: @PradeepSimha I have looked around but I didnt see anything where the value of the key is an array. I saw some stuff where it would loop but I couldnt apply it here

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(your json response);
JSONObject participants= (JSONObject) json.get("metadata").get("participants");
```